# Using logical equivalences to show $(A \Delta B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \Delta (B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I'm trying to show $(A \Delta B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \Delta (B \cap C)$ using logical equivalences.

(NOTE: "$\Delta$" denotes *exclusive or*, i.e. $A \Delta B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$.)

My workings so far:

\begin{align*}
x ∈ (A △ B) ∩ C 
  & \iff x ∈ (A △ B) ∧ x ∈ C  &&\text{(definition of ∩)} 
\\& \iff [(x ∈ A \lor x ∈ B)  ∧ ¬(x ∈ A  ∧ x ∈ B)] ∧ x ∈ C  &&\text{(definition of △)}
\\ \text{Let $P = x ∈ A$, $Q = x ∈ B$, $R = x ∈ C$} 
\\& \iff [(P \lor Q)  ∧ ¬(P  ∧ Q)] ∧ R
\\& \iff [(P \lor Q) ∧ R] ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q)  &&\text{(associativity + commutativity)}
\end{align*}

This is close to the result, I just need to turn $P \land Q$ into $P \land R \land Q \land R$, but I'm not sure how to do this. I tried using the tautology law $P ∧ ⊤ ⟺ P$ to "create" an $R$ term. However, this also introduces an $¬R$ term, which I cannot get rid of:

\begin{align*} 
[(P \lor Q) ∧ R] ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q) 
& \iff [(P \lor Q) ∧ R] ∧ ¬[(P ∧ Q) ∧ (R \lor ¬R)]  &&\text{(P ∧ ⊤ ⟺ P)}
\\& \iff [(P \lor Q) ∧ R] ∧ ¬[(P ∧ (R \lor ¬R)) ∧ (Q ∧ (R \lor ¬R))]  &&\text{(distributivity)}
\end{align*}

**Could someone please give me a hint as to what I could have used in place of $P ∧ ⊤ ⟺ P$?**

I also tried $(P ∧ Q) ∧ (R \lor T)$, but this collapses back into $(P ∧ Q)$ via the absorption law.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to get the text to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that x is in (A XOR B) $\cap$ C. Two cases, WLOG assume that x is in A, not in B and in C.  But then x is certainly in A $\cap$ C, and since it is not in B, it cannot be in B $\cap$ C. But this suffices.

For the other direction, again assume WLOG that x is in $A \cap C$ and not in $B \cap C$. It follows that x is in A, x is in C. Suppose that x were in B. Then it would be in B $\cap C$ since it is also in C. Hence, x is not in B. But this suffices.

Comment: Thanks @Papuseme, but is there a way to show this with equivalences? I'm curious to know how I can get to the RHS from where I got stuck.

Comment: @user51462 these are equivalences, we've just shown both directions.

Comment: Yes, I've upvoted. It's just that the book hasn't covered double inclusion yet (see question 13 [here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=lptwaMuAtBAC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false)). We've mainly been using the logical equivalence laws or Venn diagrams to prove identities, so I figured I would use the former since I'm wary of proof by picture. Pg 41 does have an example of how to use propositional logic to show that one set is a subset of another, but double inclusion is only introduced in the next chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Always work with both the LHS and RHS to make your life simpler.

RHS := $(A \cap C) \Delta (B \cap C) = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) \setminus ((A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C))$

which becomes

$= (A \cup B) \cap C \setminus A \cap B \cap C$

$= (A \cup B) \cap C \cap (\neg A \cup \neg B \cup \neg C)$

But since $x \in C$, then $x \not \in \neg C$ and we can get rid of the $\cup \neg C$

It's straightforward to get to $(P \lor Q) ∧ R] ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q)$ by applying De Morgan's.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie, I was thinking about using both sides too, but wasn't sure if it was safe to do so when proving identities. [This site](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/proving.htm#:~:text=But%20you%20won%27t%20have%20proved%2C%20logically%2C%20that%20the%20original%20equation%20was%20actually%20true.) advises against it: "if you work on both sides and work down to where the sides are equal, you will only have shown that, if the starting equation is true, then you can arrive at another true equation. But you won't have proved, logically, that the original equation was actually true."

Comment: If you're dealing with equivalences, if you have some things that are equivalent to the LHS and some that are equivalent to the RHS, all you have to do is prove that one thing that's equivalent to the LHS is equivalent to one thing that's equivalent to the RHS.

For equivalences (ie $\iff$) you can often afford to be a little less cautious about making sure to only work with one side, as opposed to if you're chaining together implications (ie $\implies$).

Comment: Thank you, I've upvoted your solution.